# Arduino w/ Atmega328: can't clear the watchdog

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, watchdog

I'm using the onboard software watchdog facility of an Atmega328 like documented [here](http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~c296/resources/tools/doc/avr-libc/avr-libc-user-manual-1.7.1/group__avr__watchdog.html).
My purpose is to limit to 2 seconds the execution of a portion of code that could lead to endless computation.

This is the pseudo-code scheme:

```
enable watchdog (2 seconds)
run may-be-endless code
clear watchdog
run the rest
```

The rest of the code should be run if the may-be-endless code manage to run in the given amount of time, otherwise the whole program must be restarted.

This is the Arduino code I loaded into the board:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Started");

  wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);
  Serial.println("watchdog ON");

  wdt_reset();
  Serial.println("watchdog OFF");

}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("loop...");
  delay(1000);
}
```

At this point, the expected output should be an endless printing of `loop...` messages, after the ones in the setup (`Started`, `watchdog ON`/`OFF`).

Surprisingly, what I get instead is this:

```
Started
watchdog ON
watchdog OFF
loop...
loop...
loop...
Started
watchdog ON
watchdog OFF
loop...
loop...
loop...
Started
watchdog ON
watchdog OFF
loop...
loop...
[...]
```

Appartently the watchdog is being set but can't be cleared. How come?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wdt_reset()
```

does not *disable* the watchdog, it merely *resets* its timer, delaying the expiration.

You probably want

```
wdt_disable()
```

However, your overall approach may not be the most sound - letting the watchdog expire can be clever, but it is also fairly heavy-handed compared to approaches such as using a normal timer interrupt or having your code limit itself.  Normally the watchdog is for unanticipated errors.

Comment: Thank you... I feel ashamed that I didn't check `wdt_disable` before, it was that easy. I was distracted by several how-tos that I read which stated that `wdt_reset` was the way, and also the documentation was a little bit ambiguos to me.

Answer (score 5):

To disable the watchdog timer call [wdt_disable()](http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~c296/resources/tools/doc/avr-libc/avr-libc-user-manual-1.7.1/group__avr__watchdog.html#gab3784e1b871d61ed338da5658184b725).  All `wdt_reset()` does is reset the watchdog timeout, which in your case is redundant: you just turn it on two lines above. `wdt_reset()` does not turn the watchdog timer off (contrary your serial output).